# Format the output of "read_file uptime" in i3status

Tags: i3, proc, uptime

I'm trying to display my system uptime with i3status. This is what I have in my `i3status.conf` file:

```
read_file uptime {
    format = "%title: %content"
    path = "/proc/uptime"
}
```

However the output is in seconds, as can be seen in this screenshot, which is obviously not ideal:

[image]

Is there a way I am able to format this, to display for example in the format of:

```
DD:HH:MM:SS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### My solution

**1.  Create a very very short script**

Just create a new file and rename it `uptime.sh`; then just copy this:

```bash
!#/bin/sh

echo "$(uptime -p)" > ~/.config/i3/uptime
```

this will append or write the output of the command `uptime -p` to a file which I chose to be in `~/.config/i3/uptime`. The command `uptime -p` shows uptime in a **pretty** format.

[image: terminal output of uptime -p]

If done correctly the contents of your `~/.config/i3/uptime` should be `up x hours, x minutes`.

Another command you can try is `uptime -s` which will show the **date and time** since your system was up.

[image: > ![f7c2568a315bba3c2ddccb96c7f9f4ee.png](:/a701cf4ddede44e991b3b70a8aef4d2c)]

**2. Create a cron job**

Just execute `crontab -e` in the terminal then append this line:

```
* * * * * /home/user/path/to/uptime.sh
```

this will execute the script every minute, therefore refreshing or overwriting the contents of uptime every minute. So that we can get the most recent uptime possible.

If you don't want the script to execute or to refresh the file every minute, you can replace `* * * * *` with `@hourly`  for just an hourly refresh of `uptime` file.

**3. Lastly, edit your `i3status` config file**

Like this:

```
# uptime
read_file uptime {
    color_good = "#ffffff"
    format = "%content"
    path = "/home/user/.config/i3/uptime"
}
```

And that's it. Restart i3 and hopefully `i3status uptime` shows up *pretty*.

Answer (score 1):

I made it even prettier with this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

uptime=$(uptime -p)
days=$(echo "$uptime" | grep -oP '\d+(?= day)')
hours=$(echo "$uptime" | grep -oP '\d+(?= hour)')
minutes=$(echo "$uptime" | grep -oP '\d+(?= minute)')

formatted_uptime=""
if [ -n "$days" ]; then
  formatted_uptime="${days}d "
fi
formatted_uptime="${formatted_uptime}${hours}h ${minutes}m"

echo "$formatted_uptime" > ~/.config/i3/scripts/uptimedm
```